# Means to get detailed font metrics?

Tags: ios, fonts

I'm puzzling how to divine more font metrics from iOS. I can accomplish my very long single line of text by paging UIViews while scrolling. I can determine where to break the strings between views by iteratively calculating it with sizeToFont, but I need the inter-character spacing (i.e. advance width) to space them accurately.
Any ideas short of full fixed or monospaced fonts? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Core Text class `CTFont` gives you some access to glyph metrics.  But really, you should try to just use Core Text to do your text rendering instead of asking it for measurements and calculating positions yourself.

[*CTFont Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFontRef/Reference/reference.html)
[*Core Text Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html)